# pyexcel - get column names and add entire rows together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyexcel

I have a couple of speadsheets:

```
Sheet 1     sheet2       sheet3

A B C     D E F     D F G

1 2 3      4 5 6     7 9 8
```

I'm using pyexcel to join rows together from spreadsheets 1 and 2, and 1 and 3, so the combined row for 1 and 2 would be:

```
A B C D E F D F G,
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and 1 and 3:

```
A B C D E F D F G
1 2 3       7 9 8
```

How can this be done in pyexcel?

Right now I have two for loops and this:

```
 if t_row['name'] is not "":
                    update_sheet[count, 'name'] = t_row['name']
```

But sheet 2 does not have F and G columns and sheet 3 does not have E and F. How do I list what columns a sheet has OR just take the whole row and join it with row and store that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear:

1. How you are reading the worksheet
2. how you want to handle the join when both sheets has values. I assume you want to sum up.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import pyexcel as pe

   a = np.array(pe.get_array(file_name='Sheet1.xlsx'))
   b = np.array(pe.get_array(file_name='Sheet2.xlsx'))
   c = np.array(pe.get_array(file_name='Sheet3.xlsx'))

   all=[a,b,c]
   max_cols = max([i.shape[1] for i in all])


   for i in range(3):
       if all[i].dtype!=np.dtype('int'): 
           all[i][all[i]=='']=0
           all[i]=all[i].astype('int')
       if (all[i].shape[1] != max_cols):
           all[i]=np.hstack([all[i], [[0]*(max_cols-all[i].shape[1])]*(all[i].shape[0])])

   np.sum(np.vstack(all), 0)
   ```

## EDIT

Using you will need no for loops (just for looping through different sheets). This will use numpy in a pythonic fashion!

```
def join_sheets(a, b):
    both = [a,b]
    max_cols = max([i.number_of_columns() for i in both])
    min_rows = min([i.number_of_rows() for i in both])
    both_arr = [np.array(i.array) for i in both]
    for i in range(2):
        both_arr[i] = np.hstack([both_arr[i], [['']*(max_cols - both_arr[i].shape[1])]*(both_arr[i].shape[0])])
    both_arr[0][0:min_rows,][both_arr[1][0:min_rows,]!=''] = both_arr[1][0:min_rows,][both_arr[1][0:min_rows,]!='']
    if (b.number_of_rows() > min_rows):
        both_arr[0] = np.vstack([both_arr[0], both_arr[1][min_rows:,]])
    a.array = both_arr[0].tolist()

sheets = pe.get_book(file_name='Sheet1.xlsx')
for i in range(1, sheets.number_of_sheets()): join_sheets(sheets[0], sheets[i])
sheets.save_as(sheets.path + '/' + sheets.filename)
```

Comment: No, actually I want Sheets 2 and 3 to overwrite sheet 1 (think pricelists for items, some items are new, some details are new).

Comment: Is there a way in pyexcel to do something like:
for row in records:
  row['mycolname']='updated description'
?

Comment: have you considered using [Sheet.to_records](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.Sheet.to_records.html#pyexcel.Sheet.to_records)?